# Three20 Thumbnail tutorial for Xcode 4.2?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, three20, photo-gallery

I am new to iOS development and was trying to learn to use Three20's Thumbnail feature.
Can someone point me to a tutorial or give me an example of basic use?
I'm using Xcode 4.2,Storyboard, and ARC.
I've tried the tutorial from Ray Wenderlich(http://www.raywenderlich.com/1430/how-to-use-the-three20-photo-viewer),
but it doesn't work for me and his source-code throws a ton of errors.

Thanks!

-Shredder2794

Answer (score 0):

I never used Three20, but Jeff Verkoeyens [Nimbus](http://nimbuskit.info/) framework ist pretty awesome and the documentation is much much better, which is (in my view) essential for people just starting out with iOS development :)

Take a look at his [github repo](https://github.com/jverkoey/nimbus) there is a [sample application](https://github.com/jverkoey/nimbus/tree/master/examples/photos/NetworkPhotoAlbums) implementing the *Nimbus Photo Module* or the [docs](http://docs.nimbuskit.info/) ("Modules" > "Nimbus Photos").

Comment: You could be a little bit more precise ;) Try grabbing [JSONKit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit) manually and put it into the `thirdparty/JSONKit` directory. That should fix your errors.